# How to deal with File Exception: cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Tags: c#, exception, streamwriter

How to deal with the this Exception. I have a text file. And this code rewrites the file every 3 sec. At the same time another MS Excel file reads the data from the file. And sometimes I get this exception.

Is there a way for StreamWriter to wait until MS Excel finishes reading the file and start rewriting the file right after that?

```
string path = @"C:\My Path\my_file.txt";

 using (StreamWriter fs = new StreamWriter(File.OpenWrite(path)))
  {
    fs.Write(text);
    fs.Close();
  }
```

Comment: Excel will not release the file until you close it.

Comment: This is the exact reason why you should always handle an IO exception

Comment: No, excel just reads the data from the text file every 3 seconds. It works fine mostly, but now and then it throws this exception..

Comment: You need to use `lock` while rewrite

Comment: Steve: How can I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to check if a file is in use?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/876473/is-there-a-way-to-check-if-a-file-is-in-use)

Comment: @usmanlqbal The process that reads the file would need to use that same lock in order for synchronization to work..

Comment: @Totallama check the duplicate link. This exactly describes your needs i think.

Comment: Matias Cicero: How can I do that? I have VBA script (macro) in Excel that refreshes the cell, that is set to get data from the text file..

Comment: Lock just helps on multithreading. But if another file outside your code access the same file, this will not work i think.

Comment: 1. Check the duplicate link. 2. Catch the exception and wait the next 3sek.

Comment: @Totallama You can't do it. `lock` was designed for multithreading synchronization. We're talking about different processes here.

Comment: You could use a named mutex.

Comment: Sebi, how can I catch the exception?

Comment: SLaks: How should I do this?

Answer (score -1):

This is one way:

```
string path = @"C:\My Path\my_file.txt";
string text = "Declare text variable so this code compiles";
FileStream fileS = null;
bool done = false;
while (!done)
{
    done = true;

    try
    {
        fileS = File.OpenWrite(path);
    }
    catch (IOException ex)
    {
        done = false;
    }
}

using (StreamWriter fs = new StreamWriter(fileS))
{
    fs.Write(text);
    fs.Close();
};
```

I would also add in a `StopWatch` call to have the above `while` loop timeout after so long, and possibly a small `Thread.Sleep()` so you don't spin at full speed while essentially trying to obtain the `FileStream` lock.